# Call to a member function store() on null laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-7

When im trying to edit users post without picture i got this error "Call to a member function store() on null" but when im trying edit users post with picture i dont get errors.

Here is my html code

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <div class="ur-thumb">
        <label for="picture">
            <input id="picture" type="file" name="cv_picture" style="display: none" onchange="readUrl(this)">
            <img id="myImage" src="{{Storage::url($usersCv->picture)}}" class="img-responsive pointer" alt="" />
        </label>

    </div>
    @error('cv_picture')
    <strong style="color: red">{{$message}}</strong>
    @enderror
</div>
```

Here is my controller

```
  public function updateUserCv(CvRequest $request, $id)
{
    $userId = Auth::id();
    Cv::where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->update([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'surname' => $request['surname'],
            'father_name' => $request['fatherName'],
            'gender' => $request['gender'],
            'year' => $request['year'],
            'category_id' => $request['catId'],
            'position_name' => $request['position'],
            'type_id' => $request['typId'],
            'education' => $request['education'],
            'education_description' => $request['about_education'],
            'experience_id' => $request['expId'],
            'experience_descriptions' => $request['about_work'],
            'city_id' => $request['cityId'],
            'salary' => $request['salary'],
            'skills' => $request['skills'],
            'other_information' => $request['other'],
            'mobile' => $request['mobile'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'picture' => ($request->file('cv_picture')->store('public/profile')),

        ]);
    toastr()->success('Success.', 'ok!');
    return redirect('user-cv/'.$id);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an expression `$request->file('cv_picture')`, which returns `null` and then you try to call method `store` on it.

To fix it, add a check for the returned value - something like

```
'picture' => $request->file('cv_picture') ? $request->file('cv_picture')->store('public/profile') : null
```

**Update**: ok, I missed that image may not be re-uploaded when editing the record. So you need to prepare the data for **update()** method separately and only set picture property if it exists. Something like this:

```
public function updateUserCv(CvRequest $request, $id)
{
    $update_data = [
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'surname' => $request['surname'],
        'father_name' => $request['fatherName'],
        'gender' => $request['gender'],
        'year' => $request['year'],
        'category_id' => $request['catId'],
        'position_name' => $request['position'],
        'type_id' => $request['typId'],
        'education' => $request['education'],
        'education_description' => $request['about_education'],
        'experience_id' => $request['expId'],
        'experience_descriptions' => $request['about_work'],
        'city_id' => $request['cityId'],
        'salary' => $request['salary'],
        'skills' => $request['skills'],
        'other_information' => $request['other'],
        'mobile' => $request['mobile'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
    ];
    $file = $request->file('cv_picture');
    if ($file) {
        $update_data['picture'] = $file->store('public/profile');
    }
    $userId = Auth::id();
    Cv::where('id', $id)
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->update($update_data);
    toastr()->success('Success.', 'ok!');
    return redirect('user-cv/'.$id);

}
```

Comment: thank you for question but this code deleting my old picture

Comment: Didn't you have the problem of deleting the old image with the old code? Anyway, I've updated the answer. I hope this helps.